# Trouble connecting a socket from android client app to server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I'm having trouble connecting a socket from my android phone to my computer running netcat listening on a port (5555).

What I run in my android app:

```
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("My IP number here (not local IP)", 5555);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes("Hello!");
        s.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the line I use for netcat: `nc -l 5555`

I'm not sure what I'm missing.. 
I've forwarded the port on my router and rebooted the router. Added permission to internet in my android app.
The phone is connected via 3G and my computer is connected via broadband.
netcat is allowed in my firewall.

I get a `SocketTimeoutException` error in my app when trying to connect.

I guess the router takes care of handling which computer in the LAN will receive the request.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

**EDIT:** I think I might have tracked down the problem.. I have two options on my router `Virtual Server` and `Port forwarding`. I don't know which to set to port 5555 in both UDP/TCP.
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4385192/2011-11-19%2003.17.53%20pm.png]
[image]
From what I understand it's `Virtual Server` I should use instead of the port forwarding? If so, could someone clarify the difference between the two?

Comment: I agree with @Brett Hale. Try outToServer.flush(), before s.close(). In which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Have you set a ServerSocket object in your Server class to listen for requests in port 5555?

Comment: @AlbertS: I'm running netcat, a program that can be used to listen for connections, which stated above listens for requests on port 5555 in the line `nc -l 5555` above.

Comment: @Zolomon Ok, I misunderstood, sorry. From documentation of netcat, I read that command, about listening for requests on a port, must be: nc -l -p port_number. Are you sure that the command nc -l 5555 is working properly?

Comment: @AlbertS: No worries. :) Yes, in the man page it says "-p *source_port*: Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.  **It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.**", if I use telnet on the computer to connect it works; "telnet 127.0.0.1 5555" - but since I try to connect remotely outside of my LAN I'm guessing something isn't propagating through the necessary layers..

Comment: @Zolomon I understood. This a page about the difference between virtual server and port forwarding: http://www.dlink.cc/knowledgebase/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-server-and-port-forwarding.html

Comment: And: http://superuser.com/questions/226630/are-virtual-servers-and-port-forwarding-the-same-thing

Comment: Still no success though, my configuration for Virtual Server would be the same for the Port Forwarding if I understood the second answer in the link you posted, @AlbertS. :/ @BrettHale: The outToServer.flush() didn't change anything btw. I receive a timeout informed by the `SocketTimeoutException` but I don't know what causes it.

Comment: @Zolomon I'm sorry you still got no success. Yes, your configuration would be the same. I have a router, and some time ago, to redirect internet traffic on a port to a specific LAN IP address, I used a Virtual server setting. Try the Virtual Server settings, you could get success ;)

Comment: @AlbertS: I tried both, and neither worked. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My computer had changed local IP since last configuration, so my `Virtual Server`/`Port Forwarding` rules did not apply, so I updated it (from 192.168.0.199 -> 192.168.0.19*6*) and now it works excellently.

So all steps applied:

- Set a rule for `Virtual Server`/`Port Forwarding` on your router .
- Set a rule for `Inbound Filtering` on your router in case you wish to only allow a whitelisted IP to connect and propagate to next security layer.
- If your router has any other firewall settings, create rules to allow your connections to be made.
- On your server/computer allow the ports in your firewall, or the application you're running to receive inbound connections.
- **Profit!!!**

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. It was only a changed IP address..Maybe the next time it's better to assign the same IP address related to a specific MAC address. It's possible to do in the LAN section, DHCP settings, of your router. I think you couldn't believe the problem was so easy to solve :-)

Comment: @AlbertS: Thank you for your sincere help. :)